# Splitting by combination of 2 factors

Tags: r, split, tibble

I have a tibble with 3 columns, named "A" and "B" and "C":

```
A | B | C
1   a   2017
1   b   2017
1   a   2018
1   b   2017
2   a   2017
2   a   2018
etc..
```

I would like to have a list of all items in column B for each combination of A and C. For example for [1,2017] I get [a,b].

I can do it when I have only 2 columns using split:

```
split(tibble$B, tibble$A)
```

which returns a list of lists. I am not sure how to do it with 3 columns, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# data must be data.table format..
# use setDT(mydata) if it is not.
DT <- fread("A  B  C
1   a   2017
1   b   2017
1   a   2018
1   b   2017
2   a   2017
2   a   2018")

lapply(split(DT, by = c("A", "C"), keep.by = FALSE), unique)

# $`1.2017`
# B
# 1: a
# 2: b
# 
# $`1.2018`
# B
# 1: a
# 
# $`2.2017`
# B
# 1: a
# 
# $`2.2018`
# B
# 1: a
```

Comment: is it possible starting from a tibble instead of datatable?

Comment: yes.. then it should be converted to data.table, using `setDT()`, like: `lapply(split(setDT(mytibble), by = c("A", "C"), keep.by = FALSE), unique)`